# Get a field value from a SObject List (Apex)

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm facing with the current problem. 
I have the following code which is a list of SObject and I want to get "CreatedDate" field.
I really appreciate ur time and comments, thanks.

```
public static Object testMeth() {
    List<SObject> leadsAndOpps = new List<SObject>();
    List<Lead> lstLead = [Select Id, Name, CreatedDate FROM Lead];
    List<Opportunity> lstOpp = [Select Id, Name, CreatedDate FROM Opportunity];

    //Assign first and second List to Sobject List
    leadsAndOpps.addAll(lstLead);
    leadsAndOpps.addAll(lstOpp);

    for(SObject lstExa : leadsAndOpps) {
        String getName = (String)lstExa.get('Name'); = This example works cool
        DateTime getDateVal = (DateTime)lstExa.get(CreatedDate); = Variable doesn't exists
    }
 return leadsAndOpps;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SObject.get() method is expecting a string representing the field API Name. If you put 'CreatedDate' in quotes, it should be fine. What you are passing in now is perceived as an undeclared variable named CreatedDate.